# Can't see my button when I run the program on my iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, storyboard

Why can't I see my button when I run my program but in Xcode 8 I can see it. It's over a view and looks like the button you press to take a photo with in snapchat.

I'm new to Xcode and swift so if there is anything I need to know with Xcode or the storyboard that can help me with these problems please tell me. 
[image]

The code for the view:

```
 import UIKit
 import AVFoundation
 import QuartzCore

 class View1: UIViewController , AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate{

let captureSession          = AVCaptureSession()

var previewLayer:               CALayer!

var captureDevice:              AVCaptureDevice!


@IBOutlet weak var cameraView:  UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}


/*



 This is a function to prepair the camera

 and check that there is a camera.



 If there isn't a camera on the device

 then get you will get a error.



 */

func prepareCamera()

{



    captureSession.sessionPreset     = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080





    if let availableDevices                  = AVCaptureDeviceDiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                                                                                                           mediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo,
                                                                                                                           position: .back).devices

    {



        captureDevice = availableDevices.first

        beginSession()



    }





}



func beginSession()

{



    do

    {



        let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

        captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)



    }

    catch

    {



        print(error.localizedDescription)

        /*



         Figure out what to do here

 */

    }



    if let previewLayer                          = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)

    {



        self.previewLayer                        = previewLayer

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(
        self.previewLayer)

        self.previewLayer.frame                  = self.view.layer.frame

        self.previewLayer.frame.size             = self.view.layer.frame.size

        captureSession.startRunning()



        let dataOutput                           = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

        dataOutput.videoSettings                 = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString
                                                                        ): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]


        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true


        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput)

        {

            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)


        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.PhotoAllergy.captureQueue")
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)



    }









}



//func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didDrop sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
//yeeye
//}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    prepareCamera()

}








override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}


 }
```

Comment: Please include a picture of what your view controller should look like in Storyboard and how it looks like when running the code. If you are adding any UI elements from code, also include the code in your question. Are you using Autolayout?

Comment: is that you added sufficient constraint into view for button?

Comment: Add some screenshots!

Comment: @sabarivasagan i can't because i need reputation :(

Comment: it might be you are adding but its out of view and is not visible. Add constraints to your button and view containig it.

Comment: You can add image through link!. Just upload here. I will edit it.  @Philip J

Comment: @sabarivasagan Thanks! Give me 10 min I'm not by my macbook right now!

Comment: Ok ;) @Philip J

Comment: @sabarivasagan I'm so sorry I had unexpected guests before I could type to you :( https://imgur.com/a/vuSn4

Comment: @DávidPásztor I have updated my answer! Please take a look again

Comment: @Jaydeep yes I added My code and pictures! Please look Again!

Answer (score 2):

Add constraints.
Follow these images

[image]
[image]

Good luck, you can comment here if you have any questions about this.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I have no clue what the problem is but I added a image if you would like to give some other possible way to fix this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

do the following

select your button in the storyboard view controller and follow the steps in the screen shot
press the button add constraints
run the app

[image]

Please make the viewController as the initial view controller as specified in the image below

[image]

Comment: This didn't work but I have added a image if that could help you make a second try at helping me. Thanks!

Comment: @PhilipJ have you tried adding the constraints on the button?

Comment: @PhilipJ from the story board screenshot you pasted, i see that it is not a root view controller. How are you loading this view?

Comment: It's a XIB or NIB file or whatever people like to call it and yes I have constraints and they are blue (I think thats good). Im using a scroll view so I used 2 XIB(NIB?) files with it.

Comment: @PhilipJ i updated the answer please check the next image that i attached

Comment: It was already checked. The scrollview and all that works just the button doesn't show up. Can it be something about the fact that I have the button over the view and that isn't possible? Do you have to think about where you put the button (far left by the viewcontroller scene stuff)? (I have included an image if you want to look so I haven't placed it wrong)

Comment: @PhilipJ it seems that the photo button is inside the camera view.
please remove the constraints and try bringing it out of the cameraview

also make sure that the placements of the views are like this
`-View
--CameraView
--PhotoButton`


Both the cameraView and Photo button should be at the same level

Comment: Can you share the code via git? I can look and try to fix it!

Comment: Honestly I have never used git but I'll try to look it up thanks!

Comment: How? (sorry I'm new to git or do you mean through some other way?)

Comment: Ok so before I was about to send I checked if i could add a button over my second XIB's view (they have the same things in them just one of them is using AVFoundation to get a camera previewlayer) and it worked to put the button in the same place as I put the other camera. Can I send the code of the camera view since that seems to be the problem?

Comment: Can't really say where the problem will be. Will have to go through it and then i can tell you.

Comment: Can you find the issue? :)

Comment: Yeah i have found it. the problem is with captureSession.startRunning.
now it shows the button after few seconds

Comment: How can I fix it and THANK YOU!!

Comment: sorry i was wrong. the problem dosen't seem to be fixed by bringing the sublayer of previewLayer to the back.

Comment: Ok please tell me if you find something and Thank you!

Comment: This bug or whatever it is, is really weird nobody seems to know how to fix it